# Can you follow a religion?

Tags: word-usage, collocation

The case is:

> Most of the interviewed reported to **follow** some kind of religion.

It seems awkward to say that, but can it be said so? Are there alternative ways for it?

PS. I'd say something like: "... to take part in some kind of religious group."

Comment: It's a common idiom, though the wording you quote is a bit awkward.

Comment: May I attempt to make the quote less awkward with the following edit: Most of those interviewed reported that they followed some kind of religion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Following a religion" is an expression. It has some interesting variations in frequency of usage between religions, but there are definitely some other ways to say this.

It's important to remember that these different phrasings can carry subtle nuances, which is [important with things like surveys](http://www.pewresearch.org/methodology/u-s-survey-research/questionnaire-design/). For this reason, I would suggest that you stay with the original wording, or rephrase the statement instead of rewording it completely.

But I will list some alternatives:

- Identify as religious
- Belong to a religion
- Claim they are religious
- Are affiliated with a religion

(You can probably find a whole lot more to list.)